# Methods defined as TestMethod do not support Web service callouts - Causing tests to fail instead of skipped - Began 10-21-2015

Tags: unit-test, callout

Starting recently we are now getting this error during tests:

> Methods defined as TestMethod do not support Web service callouts

Rather than saying "Test Method Skipped" they are **failing** and causing deployments to not be able to complete.

The problem is that many of these are due to **managed packages** that do not implement protection from client tests and do not implement mock interface thus attempting to callout during test methods.

Is anyone else seeing this issue? Anyone found a fix.

Also, the stack trace string is simply blank in the test execution summary. The debug log show a managed package attempting to make a callout

**Update** Based on Crop's comment I thought I had a workaround BUT alas, the test is inserting / updating a record which causes the managed package to attempt a callout and since it is a trigger I have to have at least 1% coverage so I have to insert or update a record which causes the managed package triggers to fire....Oh vicious circle.

**Update 2**

I changed the old trigger to a process builder process which removed the need for the trigger. Still does not solve the problem if it was a more complex trigger....

**Update 3**

Implementing the managed Package mock response class still produces the error. It seems that a test.setMock within a local test does not get utilized by the namespaced class making the callout during a test.

Comment: when you deploy via changesets - you have the option to avoid running managed package tests (workaround)

Comment: @crop1645 - Thanks, unfortunately now I have to create a sandbox, etc, etc, etc as I was using MM to deploy directly to production...Will have to check how to set the setting in MM. As an aside, is this a bug or a new "Enhancement"

Comment: I don't have your use case in my orgs but I can say that Winter 16 deployments now seem to exercise custom component controllers in VF email messages used in Approval Processes if you enter an Approval Process - and if said custom controller isn't tolerant of null values, it fails. Wasn't an issue in Summer 15 as the custom controller was never invoked.  I think as with many SFDC releases, test behavior is not always guaranteed

Comment: @crop1645 - Unfortunately - that will not work as a test (local) inserts a record and the package makes a callout because of that record insert....ugh. I wish packages properly implemented mock interfaces......

Comment: I know when I have built a package that uses callouts, I had to expose a global method in my package that sets the mock interface in my package as part of your setup to avoid this happening...this is going to get messy very quickly...

Comment: @BritishBoyinDC - I just did a basic test and setting the test.setMock() to the managed packages global response generator still produced the error that Test methods do not support callouts. So it seems that there may be an issue with something that prevents the managed package callouts being mocked when the mock is set in a local class.......Not sure of exact cause yet....All I know is it does not work.....Maybe it is unique to something else going on? Can you confirm that from a local test, setting the namespaced global class in set mock actually works? cause in my tests it does not

Comment: I just ran a test that did the following on CS24 and it worked:
Local test first calls a global method in managed package that sets up webservice mock...Local test then calls some code in Managed Package that would initiate callout...test passed

Comment: @BritishBoyinDC - do you mean you used test.setmock(.......,global managed class)? and it worked? maybe there is something in their (my org) code that is not mocked then hmm....Or maybe it is the fact that their code was an Future methods executed as part of a trigger. Nothing in my org called their code (except the mock response setting). It happens as a result of a trigger (managed) when the record is inserted...Maybe those differences are important (the future part)

Comment: Not quite - I called a global method called settestdata in my package which does the test.setmock. But I think the @future might be the problem - they are always tricky to get working with callouts in tests...my stuff is all synchronous

Comment: @BritishBoyinDC - Ok. I may have to make a test package that simply add a trigger to account that executes a future method to make a callout. Then provide a mock global class. Then install it is a local org and test result. Need something to prove to SF that it is an issue and I keep getting told to just use the global mock glass provided by the managed package but it is not working....ugh. They said they had to release this patch to fix another bug and if they rolled it back then the bug would reappear....

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Salesforce just posted an alert for partners about this, which is odd, this would normally be a known issue - and partner alerts generally don't go out for those.

I'll quote the most relevant bits here:

> **Who is impacted by this?** Any partner whose org contained tests with
>   callouts or calls to getContent before our recent Winter '16 patch
>   release (patch 198.7).
>
> **What is the change?** After a recent Winter ‘16 patch release, customers
>   and partners may be seeing the following error message when running a
>   test that attempts a callout or calls getContent, “Method defined as
>   testMethod do not support web service callouts, test failed”.
>
> **Why is this change happening?** Prior to this recent change, tests using
>   callouts/Pagereference.getContent() were marked as "skipped". However,
>   these tests NEVER worked, but never failed either. Deployments were
>   allowed to proceed without fixing these tests.
>
> As of patch 198.7, this behavior has been changed, such that these
>   tests are now correctly marked as "failed" when executed.
>
> **What action do I need to take?** If you and your customers are
>   experiencing this, here are two recommended workarounds:
>
> 1. Remove or comment out the tests that were previously being skipped. Please note that since those test classes have always been skipped,
>      commenting them out now will not affect the other test classes nor
>      reduce the testing done on the application upon deployment.
> 2. Implement HTTP Callouts by implementing the HttpCalloutMock Interface. See this article on the Developer site for more information
>      https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_restful_http_testing_httpcalloutmock.htm

Comment: That is a huge misstep essentially rendering customers unable to deploy in some circumstances

Comment: Yes that is how we discovered it as well, during an attempted deployment to production. Quite unsettling.